# How do I build a query to find ownership through transaction history?

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm currently working on a feature that can contract all objects that a certain user owns, by only using a transaction history.

This is how the transaction table looks like:

**TRANSACTION**

- id

- sender (User)

- recipient (User)

- object_id

- created_on

- modified_on

I've been trying creating a query for this, but I can't seem to figure it out. How can I track which objects belongs to a given user.

Many thanks in advance!

Geoffrey

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, your transaction history seems to have no concept of "owning", so your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Every object has an initial owner, and by following the transaction history, you can see who the current owner is of the object.
The output should be an array of transactions that contain the current owner. So the last record of each contract that is in the transaction history.

Comment: Your database design (i.e. a single transaction history table) is not suitable for your purpose. While it may be possible to do what you need, it's certainly a _very_ suboptimal design.

Comment: So you're looking for the recipient user in the latest transaction per object_id? This sounds like a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem. This general type of question is asked frequently on Stack Overflow, you can probably find a solution by reading some answers on that tag.

Comment: Thanks very much! I ended up with this:
`$query = 'SELECT object_id
            FROM transaction
            WHERE recipient = :recipient
            GROUP BY object_id
            ORDER BY created_on DESC';`